# How to fix "writing-mode vertical-rl" not display correctly via Google Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and using  html tag which is inserted via WPBakery PageBuilder. and I have set class for

as writing-mode: vertical-rl;

Things work perfect in Firefox as it is vertical-oriented and is displayed in one line, but in [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNPU4.jpg) it is seperate into two line.

Here is my [CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIEdq.jpg)

Here is my html

```
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tbody align="center">
<tr align="center">
<td rowspan="2" width="15%">ผลิตภัณฑ์</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="10%">เกรด</td>
<td colspan="3" width="20%">มาตรฐานเปรียบเทียบ</td>
<td colspan="9" width="20%">ส่วนผสมทางเคมี (%)</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="10%">สภาพจำหน่าย</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="10%">การใช้งาน</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="15%">ตัวอย่างการใช้งาน</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="64">AISI</td>
<td width="81">DIN</td>
<td width="76">JIS</td>
<td width="26">C</td>
<td width="26">Si</td>
<td width="26">Mn</td>
<td width="26">Cr</td>
<td width="26">Mo</td>
<td width="26">Ni</td>
<td width="26">V</td>
<td width="26">W</td>
<td width="26">Oth.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="17" width="1090">เหล็กอะไหล่ชุบแข็ง</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="162"><img src="http://maxsteelthai.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image001.png" alt="" /></td>
<td width="64">1.7225</td>
<td width="64">
<p class="testnew">4140</p>
</td>
<td width="81">
<p class="testnew">42CrMo4</p>
</td>
<td width="76">
<p class="testnew">SCM440H</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.38-0.45</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.10-0.40</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.6-0.9</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.9-1.2</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.15-0.3</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">-</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">-</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">-</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">P/0.035, S/0.035</p>
</td>
<td width="102">Pre-Hardened 28-33 HRC</td>
<td width="250">มีส่วนผสมของ Cr-Mo-Mn เหมาะกับงานอะไหล่ชิ้นส่วนเครื่องจักร เช่น เพลาขับ เพลาข้อเหวี่ยง ก้านสูบ เฟือง บุช</td>
<td width="162"><img src="http://maxsteelthai.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image003.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="162"><img src="http://maxsteelthai.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image006.png" alt="" /></td>
<td width="64">1.6582</td>
<td width="64">
<p class="testnew">4340</p>
</td>
<td width="81">
<p class="testnew">34CrNiMo6</p>
</td>
<td width="76">
<p class="testnew">SNCM8</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.30-0.38</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.4</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.5-0.8</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">1.3-1.7</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.15-0.3</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">1.3-1.7</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">-</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">-</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">P/0.035, S/0.030</p>
</td>
<td width="102">Pre-Hardened 25-30 HRC</td>
<td width="250">มีส่วนผสมของ Cr-Mo Low Alloyed เหมาะกับงานอะไหล่ชิ้นส่วนเครื่องจักรรองรับความเครียดสูงได้ดี เช่น เพลาขับ เพลาข้อเหวี่ยง ก้านสูบ เฟือง บุช</td>
<td width="162"><img src="http://maxsteelthai.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image016.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and here my css

```
p.testnew {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks.
I have just added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `white-space: pre;` to forbid the browser from breaking this into multiple lines.

```css
p.testnew {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tbody align="center">
<tr align="center">
<td rowspan="2" width="15%">ผลิตภัณฑ์</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="10%">เกรด</td>
<td colspan="3" width="20%">มาตรฐานเปรียบเทียบ</td>
<td colspan="9" width="20%">ส่วนผสมทางเคมี (%)</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="10%">สภาพจำหน่าย</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="10%">การใช้งาน</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="15%">ตัวอย่างการใช้งาน</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="64">AISI</td>
<td width="81">DIN</td>
<td width="76">JIS</td>
<td width="26">C</td>
<td width="26">Si</td>
<td width="26">Mn</td>
<td width="26">Cr</td>
<td width="26">Mo</td>
<td width="26">Ni</td>
<td width="26">V</td>
<td width="26">W</td>
<td width="26">Oth.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="17" width="1090">เหล็กอะไหล่ชุบแข็ง</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="162"><img src="http://maxsteelthai.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image001.png" alt="" /></td>
<td width="64">1.7225</td>
<td width="64">
<p class="testnew">4140</p>
</td>
<td width="81">
<p class="testnew">42CrMo4</p>
</td>
<td width="76">
<p class="testnew">SCM440H</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.38-0.45</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.10-0.40</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.6-0.9</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.9-1.2</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.15-0.3</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">-</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">-</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">-</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">P/0.035, S/0.035</p>
</td>
<td width="102">Pre-Hardened 28-33 HRC</td>
<td width="250">มีส่วนผสมของ Cr-Mo-Mn เหมาะกับงานอะไหล่ชิ้นส่วนเครื่องจักร เช่น เพลาขับ เพลาข้อเหวี่ยง ก้านสูบ เฟือง บุช</td>
<td width="162"><img src="http://maxsteelthai.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image003.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="162"><img src="http://maxsteelthai.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image006.png" alt="" /></td>
<td width="64">1.6582</td>
<td width="64">
<p class="testnew">4340</p>
</td>
<td width="81">
<p class="testnew">34CrNiMo6</p>
</td>
<td width="76">
<p class="testnew">SNCM8</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.30-0.38</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.4</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.5-0.8</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">1.3-1.7</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">0.15-0.3</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">1.3-1.7</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">-</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">-</p>
</td>
<td width="26">
<p class="testnew">P/0.035, S/0.030</p>
</td>
<td width="102">Pre-Hardened 25-30 HRC</td>
<td width="250">มีส่วนผสมของ Cr-Mo Low Alloyed เหมาะกับงานอะไหล่ชิ้นส่วนเครื่องจักรรองรับความเครียดสูงได้ดี เช่น เพลาขับ เพลาข้อเหวี่ยง ก้านสูบ เฟือง บุช</td>
<td width="162"><img src="http://maxsteelthai.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image016.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much , it works perfectly.
one more question please, as you can see my code 
each <td> data has specific width and I don't want it.
so how can I set the width of the header of table column and let the rest field of column follow the header column.

Comment: Remove the width attributes, and see what you get. Maybe adding `table-layout:fixed` on the table will get closer to what you want.